# TP-LINK TL-R460, pppoe issue. Internet doesn't work for one computer in my network

Tags: windows-networking

First of all, my router info:

Firmware Version:
3.5.1 Build 070321 Rel.50877na
Hardware Version:
R460v3 1001225B

I have this router with which I want to split a pppoe connection for 3 computers. I did a reset on the router to restore it to factory defaults and configured the pppoe username and password. Out of the box(without additional configuration, connection works for 2 out of 3 computers. The third one is connected to lan network but can't resolve any websites.

The third computer doesn't have a firewall..or an issue with the lan cable or something like that. I can connect to the router from there without any problems.

So, any advice on how to troubleshoot this issue?

Comment: I have fixed this issue. If anyone has an issue like this, be sure to check at lan (obtain automatically).

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange sites 0101amt. If you have fixed the issue, please post your solution as an answer and give it the check-mark so others can find it in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that may cause this issue is using wrong dns addresses. Be sure to check if the local area network is set to obtain everything automatically.